# Stacked Bar Graph In R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, boxplot, stacked-chart

So I'm trying to make a stacked bar plot. This is all the data that needs to be in the plot. I am wanting a-e to be next to f-j. I am also trying to get the y-axis to be reasonable. For some reason it is putting numbers instead of a limit. I am probably doing it completely wrong. I've looke

```
data<- rbind(c(4655, 4212, 3838, 3583, 3124, 3078, 1411, 2589, 2524, 2429),
         c(2826, 2589, 2557, 2713, 2497, 1, 2, 66, 1757, 1822))

a <- cbind(data[, 1], 1, c("50-60", "40-49"))
b <- cbind(data[, 2], 2, c("50-60", "40-49"))
c <- cbind(data[, 3], 3, c("50-60", "40-49"))
d <- cbind(data[, 4], 4, c("50-60", "40-49"))
e <- cbind(data[, 5], 5, c("50-60", "40-49"))
f <- cbind(data[, 6], 1, c("50-60", "40-49"))
g <- cbind(data[, 7], 2, c("50-60", "40-49"))
h <- cbind(data[, 8], 3, c("50-60", "40-49")) 
i <- cbind(data[, 9], 4, c("50-60", "40-49"))
j <- cbind(data[, 10], 5, c("50-60", "40-49"))

data  <- as.data.frame(rbind(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j))
colnames(data) <-c("Number", "Year", "Age")
data$Year      <- factor(data$Year, labels = c("FY13", 
                         "FY14","FY15","FY16","FY17"))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = data$Year, y = Number, fill = Age)) + 
       geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

I am probably doing it completely wrong. I've looked and looked, but cannot find something else to help me.

Comment: I was going to say that Number is a factor in your example, you would need to convert it to numeric `data$Number <- as.numeric(data$Number)`... Check the answer by @JanLauGe to see if this is what you need...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you do not want the Year, Age groups combined... So I created another variable to keep them separate and then used `facet_grid`:

```
data <- data.frame(as.vector(data), rep(rep(1:5, each=2),2), c("50-60","40-49"), rep(c("Grp1","Grp2"), each=10))

#data  <- as.data.frame(rbind(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j))
colnames(data) <-c("Number", "Year", "Age", "Grp")
data$Year      <- factor(data$Year, labels = c("FY13", 
                                               "FY14","FY15","FY16","FY17"))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Grp, y = Number, fill = Age)) + facet_grid(~Year) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to `dodge` your position in ggplot2 like below:

**Data**:

```
data  <- as.data.frame(rbind(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j))
data <- cbind(data,Group = c(rep("a-e",5),rep("f-j",5)))
colnames(data) <-c("Number", "Year", "Age",
                   "Group")
data$Year <- factor(data$Year, labels = c("FY13","FY14","FY15","FY16","FY17"))
data$Age <- factor(data$Age)
data$Group <- factor(data$Group)
```

**Plotting**:

```
library(ggplot2)


ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Age , y = as.numeric(Number), fill = Year)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",position="dodge") + facet_grid(~Group)
```

`?ggplot2::position_dodge`

> Dodging preserves the vertical position of an geom while adjusting the
>   horizontal position.

**Output**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
# Your original data
data %>%
  # Number should be numeric
  mutate(Number = as.numeric(Number),
         # Groups ('a-e' or 'f-j') aren't in the data
         # so I am randomly generating them here
         Group = sample(c('a-e', 'f-j'), n(), replace = TRUE)) %>%
  # I assume you want one (overall) value per year, age, and group ('a-e' or 'f-j')
  group_by(Year, Age, Group) %>%
  # So we get the sum of number
  summarise(Number = sum(Number)) %>%
  # And make the plot
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Number, fill = Age, group = Group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge', width = 0.9)
```

[image]

Comment: This is very close to what I want. But I want to have a side bar graph of  a-e next to f-j.

Comment: 'a-e' and 'f-j' aren't in your example data, so I made them up randomly

Comment: I figured it out.